# Is a professor allowed to ask me what grade I got in a previous class?

Tags: united-states, professorship, grades, privacy

I'm a student in Michigan, in the United States. I've just started a class for which a previous class was the prerequisite. The professor of my current class asked that I give him my grade for that previous class. (This was an e-mail sent to me and all my classmates.) I don't like the feel of it. Does he have any right to that information? Obviously he isn't going through the system to get the information, and I feel like it's because this isn't on the level.

On further research, I found the [FERPA website](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html). It declares:

> Generally, schools must have written permission from the parent or eligible student in order to release any information from a student's education record. However, FERPA allows schools to disclose those records, without consent, to the following parties or under the following conditions (34 CFR § 99.31):
>
> - School officials with legitimate educational interest;

There are additional parties/conditions, but this is the only one that even comes close to my situation. Another reference I found is Huntingdon College's [General FERPA Information](http://hawk.huntingdon.edu/FERPA/FSINFO.HTML), which defines a **school official** as:

> a person employed by the College in an administrative, supervisory, academic or research, or support staff position;

There are other definitions, but again, this is the most applicable to my situation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71777/discussion-on-question-by-skia-heliou-is-a-professor-allowed-to-ask-me-what-grad).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the US, federal student privacy laws (FERPA) dictate that schools restrict access to student educational records, so that only those with a "legitimate educational interest" can access them. Most universities interpret this such that the student's academic advisor can automatically see their full transcripts in the student record system, but not every professor of every class the student takes.

However, just because access is not *automatic*, does not mean that it is not allowed. If a professor has a "legitimate educational interest" in a student record, then they may request access to that record. (For example, from the student's academic advisor.) "Legitimate educational interest" will be defined in the school's Student Records Policy and in their annual FERPA disclosure. For [example](http://system.suny.edu/compliance/topics/education-and-student-relations/ferpa/):

> A school official has a legitimate educational interest if the official requires the information for the purpose of fulfilling his official duties, including but not limited to:
>
> - performing a task that is specified in his or her position description or contract agreement;
> - performing a task related to a student’s education;
> - performing a task related to the discipline of a student;
> - providing a service or benefit relating to the student or student’s family, such as health care, counseling, job placement or financial aid;
> - maintaining the safety and security of the campus; or
> - participating in or conducting studies, evaluations, or assessments of educational programs.

Finally, as the student, *you* are permitted to disclose your student record to anyone you want. Someone with no educational interest in your record - e.g. your parent - could ask you questions about your educational records, and you would be free to disclose that information or not.

Comment: To this I'd add that a professor, at least generally, has a "legitimate educational interest" in a student's grade in a prerequisite course.  The student who just barely scraped by the prerequisite is different from the student who aced the course.  The former is likely to need more help.

Comment: It seems like the discussion of FERPA clouds the key idea here, which is the instructor is asking a student how well they performed in a prereq course. _Of course_, instructors have a legitimate educational interest in student performance in prerequisite courses (!).

Comment: @MadJack The OP seemed to think that the professor was doing something wrong because he wasn't "going through the system". I was trying to explain why the system is set up the way it is.

Comment: @MadJack **Legitimate** is very subjective. The definition I connect with in this sense is "accordant with law or with established legal forms and requirements". This may be a *matter of course* for you, but appeal to tradition and I don't mix

Comment: @skia.heliou That would make those articles incorrect. Obviously a piece of law that states *[omissis] under the following conditions (34 CFR § 99.31): School officials with **unlawful** educational interest;* is not a valid piece of law. Hence the term *legitimate* as synonym for *lawful* is just noise and would be safely removed from the article leaving a more neutral *educational interest*.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's nice

Comment: @skia.heliou "Legitimate education interest" is not defined in statute, but the school is required to state how it defines "legitimate educational interest" in their own policeis. Look for you a "FERPA policy" or "Student Records Policy" or similar at your own institution. I added an example to the answer. Certainly a professor inquiring about a grade for a prerequisite course for a student in their class would quality as a "legitimate educational interest" according to every definition I have ever seen.

Comment: @MadJack and ff524 and BobBrown: I have yet to see anyone provide a legitimate educational interest that the teacher has in knowing the prereq course's grade. "He might need more help" does not allow the teacher to violate FERPA. Knowing the previous grade provides plenty of potential for abuse but little potential for anything lawful or helpful in any way. A simple "Would you like extra help?" question would be superior to a "What was your grade in the prereq course?" And I have yet to see any other reasons the teacher may need this. Please supply some.

Comment: @Aaron The simplest reason is that instructors very often have to make sure each student have completed the necessary prerequisite courses with a certain minimum grade; not doing so can lead to programs being at risk of being in violation of, for instance, various accrediting board standards (this can lead to programs losing their accredited status).

Comment: @Aaron If an educator accesses a student record for reasons related to educating the student, it's not a FERPA violation. "I want to know who needs more help" is a _legally_ valid reason. So is "I want to assess the overall preparation level of the class, to decide how much time in class to allocate to review." So is "I want to know if we should restrict Advanced Basket Weaving to students who earned at least a B in Elementary Basket Weaving next year." There could be other ways to answer those questions, but accessing a student record to answer them would certainly not be a FERPA violation.

Comment: @Aaron "Legitimate educational interest" excludes idle curiosity, but not much else.

Comment: @ff524 But doesn't that (about idle curiosity) mean that a tutor (or even a friend of the student, for that matter) can go to a student's advisor and say "I'm requesting Bob's grades so that I can better tailor my tutor services to him," and have their request fulfilled without violating FERPA? And that is just an example off the top of my head; I am sure I could think of worse ones that are more murky than that. To me, it sounds like you guys are suggesting FERPA provides practically zero benefit to privacy (assuming the school did not provide grades for idle curiosity before).

Comment: And my above comment is coming from a background as a college teacher where I recall FERPA being taken much more seriously and strictly than that, in my personal experience. The colleges I worked with were afraid of the possibility of violating FERPA privacy, some administrators even afraid of violating it accidentally. You guys sound like there is nothing to be afraid of, save for negligent idle curiosity, which should not have been tolerated to begin with. If you are correct in your laissez faire interpretation, you could let schools know they don't need be nearly as careful as they are.

Comment: @Aaron No, the "legitimate educational interest" reason for accessing a student record only applies to a "school official" (typically someone employed by or under contract with the school, who accesses the record for a "legitimate educational interest" reason related to their job).

Answer (score 22):

There are very few things, if any, that professors are prohibited from asking. Asking some things (e.g., sexual orientation or marital status) might get a professor in trouble if a complaint is raised and the professor lacks a good reason for asking for the information. While asking for and obtaining previous grades could lead to a FERPA violation (or some other misdeed), I doubt a department chair would ever reprimand a professor for asking.

Now for why the professor might be asking for the grade, sometimes it is easier to ask the student then use the online system or go through the department administrator. Most likely, they are asking about the grade as a potential conversation starter. The issues they want to talk about possibly depend on the grade you got. For example, asking a D student if topic X was covered probably does not make as much sense as asking an A student. Asking a C student if they understand topic X might provide more insight than asking an A student.

I would suggest you just tell them the grade. If you are really worried tell the professor you don't like discussing grades but would be happy to talk about the content of the course.

Comment: How do you type with boxing gloves on? ;)

Comment: @skia.heliou DELETED

Comment: =D So yeah, this is still a matter of knowing my options before going in. I understand there are a lot of students and this is a research university, but being judged by numbers and letters got old a long time ago for me. Perhaps this is my preference for direct communication over derived notions

Comment: @skia.heliou for you *direct communication* is more efficient, but for the professor with 100s of students *derived notions* might work better.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why this boils down to knowing my options when I talk it over with him

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, I think there are better ways to get that information and feel of the class than asking for previous grades. I think that it is just as likely that "It can help me feel out my class" could be an excuse and cover for "I'm lazy. At the end, I'm just going to give them a random grade within 1 or 2 steps of their previous grade." I have known multiple teachers who have done things like the latter, or worse, but none that I recall who did the former.

Comment: @Aaron sure they could be doing something bad with the information, but it doesn't mean they cannot ask. If they really are that lazy, then I am not sure it is advantageous to make yourself out to be the *difficult* student.

Comment: @StrongBad I did not say they cannot ask. Any human can ask any other for anything. But I argue that is bad form, and the teacher has no legitimate educational interest in that information in the strict and intended sense of the term. "I think I could teach the class better" is not a legitimate educational interest in data that's otherwise banned. Professor could say he could teach the class better by being relaxed if the student with fairest hands gave a massage before class; maybe true but very bad form and unnecessary. Teacher can get what they need other ways, like day-1 anonymous quiz.

Answer (score 12):

When I was taking a class that required a pre-requisite and our teacher asked for the grade we got in that class he was ultimately trying to gauge his students.

He wanted to gauge how well everyone in the class understood the previous material. Based on the grades we gave him became a deciding factor on whether or not he would briefly go over the previous material the first week of class or just jump right into the new material.

I don't know this teacher but typically teacher's like to get a feel for the students that are taking their class. If a teacher can gather a better overall understanding of the students in the class they could use that information to better teach their students.

Answer (score 6):

You said you don't like the feel of the situation, but as someone with hardly any facts I would suggest turning it around and saying something like "*We both know that grades are somewhat arbitrary - what specific information are you trying to get at via my previous grade? If you're concerned that I am lacking a skill or set of knowledge that is crucial for this class, I'd be glad to answer more specific questions regarding my abilities/knowledge, and work with you so I can remedy any deficiencies in my previous coursework that we might discover together.*"

This way, you don't go straight to federal regulations in the event that the request that they're just taking a poll to see who might need extra attention/help (i.e 'don't make a federal case over it [unless it's necessary]').

But obviously if they are demanding your grade, and won't reveal why, then consider reporting it to the department chair/ombudsperson/etc. You can probably do this even if you got a good grade and you decide to share it with the instructor to get them off your back.

Comment: I agree (as @Bob Brown states), he could be scoping out students for people who need more help or less. He could also be choosing who to ignore as they aren't worth his time, or any number of things. I don't know him, and when something strikes me as off, I go with my intuition. In this case it's a matter of wanting to know my options before I go into negotiation

Comment: @skia.heliou While grades of a single students can be arbitrary, from my experience if most students in a large class got a C- in pre-req, the class on average is much less prepared to handle the second course than if most students got an A-. And this information can help me teach from the beginning at the level of the class. And note that if I ask this information from the entire class, I really don't care what YOU did in the previous class, I care in general how most of the class did in the previous course.

Comment: @NickS Something I've done in the past is to make up a very short quiz covering the topics that should already be known. If students are concerned about doing *that*, then I have told them they can feel free to submit it anonymously. Sometimes I have even said up front "You don't need to sign your name to this quiz that I give on day 1; it's just to see where the class is at."

Comment: @NickS On the other hand, if you want aggregate statistics rather than data about individuals, then you can anonymize it: for example, you could ask everyone to put a slip of paper into a hat with their grade in the prereq class with no identifying information on it. Or you could follow something like Aaron's idea. That said, in something like office hours, you might ask this of a student to help you know where to begin answering their actual question (because their question may really be rooted in something which is not exactly embedded in the question itself).

Comment: @Aaron Yes that is an idea which works in some classes, but not in all. There are quite a few classes where a 10 minutes and even a 30 minutes quiz cannot give me enough info about how much students really understood in the previous class. Last, but not least, one of the OP's complains is that the grade doesn't truly reflect how much the students understood. If that is the case, and multiple exams and assignments are not enough to paint the picture, how can a small quiz provide the same information (I know, I am just playing devil's advocate here)

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is another solution, but how effective is it. Asking them to drop a piece of paper in  a hat while holding the hat raises concerns of anonymity. And if you leave the hat outside your office, and ask them voluntarily to drop the info you need, I would be really surprised if the number of students doing that passes 20%, and I am being generous here.

Comment: @NickS Perhaps a 10-30 minute quiz doesn't tell you as much as you'd like, but it tells you more than a previous grade. It depends how the teacher perceives you. When I was a student, got A- in a class I struggled in and barely understood - thought I was in danger of failing; the A- surprised me as I was expecting F or D. I've done near perfect in others and wondered why I got B- when I was sure I aced the class completely, only to get lame excuses why I didn't deserve an A. Grade depends on teacher perception and your relationship as much as how you actually do; it's a vague metric. +1'ed btw

Comment: @NickS If all you are looking for is an aggregate compilation of the previous grades, a link to an anonymous Google survey in the email is perhaps even a better solution.  It take almost no time to do and more students are likely to just do it if it is requested in such a way.  In addition, these surveys will do aggregations for you instead of requiring the professor to go through each email and keep a tally

Comment: @PunPun1000 In theory you are right, in practice here is what happens: my University moved to completely online student evaluations. They don't allow us do paper evaluations anymore. And since this was implemented, the completion rate is usually 20% or lower, with 20% being achieved only if I mention multiple times in class that they should complete them. And the evaluations are as easy to complete, if not easier, than google surveys. And on the top of the small completion rate, if one compares the new evaluations with the old, it is typically the students which either really liked or hated..

Comment: the class which fills them. The data so badly screwed in two directions, that it becomes completely meaningless. While it is not the best approach, students will be much more compelled to answer to an e-mail from the professor then complete some anonymous survey on the website. An in class Quiz, and again I am basing the answer on my experience,  will get a much better response rate and better data than an online survey, but since it should not be graded and the students need to know that, the students will put very little effort into it. And as I mention, this is not always an option.

Answer (score 5):

To ask such questions in the U.S. is, at least, ill-considered. The obvious possible sense of it, in the best-case scenario, is out of concern whether students are adequately prepared. But, to my mind, knowing prior grades does also have great potential for prejudicing expectations on the part of the instructor. Deflecting the question would be in everyone's best interest. So, no, teachers should not ask this question (in the U.S.). And even their interest in knowing the quality of the preparation of their students, while understandable, is slightly beyond what is appropriate, except as aggregate.

EDIT: in response to one comment, I am *not* suggesting that grading might be unfair. I am suggesting that students often rise (or sink) to expectations expressed (possibly subtly) by teachers, etc.

Further, first, in the U.S., FERPA seems to indicate that current instructors are not automatically entitled to access to their (current) students' prior grades. Ok. Doesn't say they're not *allowed* to ask, but, again, the instructor will know who declined to give the info, and students may worry about that, too, since if they decline, this creates an impression, etc.

Rather than asking for the (anyway, in my opinion, dubious) info of "prior grade(s)", why not do a diagnostic/review quiz or quizzes? This gives better-quality information, and avoids all sorts of potential psychological issues.

Again, even if the instructor's intentions are good, asking for prior grades has too many problematical aspects, and a better quality sort of information can be acquired otherwise.

So, "can they ask": sure, I guess. *Should* they ask? I think not.

Comment: Would prejudiced expectations be lowered expectations or something else?

Comment: @ScottH., I'd imagine it could be many things. Possibly lowered expectations in a _good_ way, or lowered expectations in a _bad_ way. That is, to take it to extremes, presumption of success, or presumption of failure. After all, in the end, there is no truly objective measure of "success"... so it can be redefined to either include or exclude almost any given individual. Not to mention the non-objectivity of "grading" in upper division math courses, for example. (Notwithstanding the (ridiculous) pretense that "rubrics" successfully objectify everything... )

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply.  I'm struggling to reconcile my thoughts (that perfect information would be better for everyone involved, and that lack of strength in a prereq will come to light regardless) with the objections that have been given.  I guess that I haven't thought as much about human weakness coming into play.

Comment: Some people grade blind - even in the U.S., where it is not standard. I'd be more concerned about the information being requested by email than its being requested per se. There are legitimate pedagogical reasons for wanting to know this kind of information. This answer is too sweeping in its generalisations.

Comment: @cfr, I'm not referring necessarily to potentially unfair _grading_, but to the effect on students of expectations of a teacher, in terms of learning and so on: it seems that often people are affected by others' expectations. Even if previous performance is described "in aggregate", this can develop "expectations", which have an effect.

Comment: Your answer makes a sweeping generalisation about asking being inappropriate. But there are sometimes good pedagogical reasons to ask. One way or another, teaching *requires* figuring out what people already know and how well they understand and can apply it. How else are you supposed to help people learn?

Comment: @cfr Teaching *does* require figuring out what students currently do and don't know, which is exactly why it makes no sense to rely on a single piece of ambiguous information from a previous term.

Comment: It is certainly not the end of such investigation, but it can be a legitimate starting point. Especially if you wanted a general sense of where a class as a whole was starting from.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered not answering? This is an information you may or may not want to give out, and if he does not have access to it, you do not have to provide your previous grade.

From browsing this SE i have come to the impression that professors sometimes tend to not anser e-mail either, so it probably wouldn't come off as rude.

Like you stated in a comment, he either could be looking for people who need additional help or he might be checking out who is worth his time and who is not.

In any case, if you did score an acceptable grade, it wouldn't hurt to tell him after all ;)

Comment: Maybe he only wants to find out the approximate background of the students, which will tell him how many details he should give. With the students refusing to give the information, his most natural choices would be to start the class assuming that all students understood perfectly the subject in the pre-req and skip over the easy steps or go over everything. The first choice is bad FOR STUDENTS if most students in the class barely got a C-, while the second choice is bad FOR STUDENTS if they all aced the previous class. With the extra information, it would be easier to decide...

Comment: the level of details needed, while without the Prof would only get the background info from the Midterm exam...

Answer (score 1):

> The professor of my current class asked that I give him my grade for that previous class. (This was an e-mail sent to me and all my classmates.)

If the question feels intrusive, you don't need to answer.  You might respond

> I feel well prepared for this course and I'm looking forward to building on previous knowledge and skills during the coming weeks.

It sounds like the instructor didn't explain his motivation for the question, and if so, I would encourage you to let the department take a look at his email.  However, the safest way of preventing administrative bumbling that might result in retaliation would be to wait until the end of the semester.

It's very possible that the instructor made an honest mistake but meant well, and would benefit from some departmental guidance.

However, if the instructor's intention was for students to share their previous grade with the whole group, that would be different.  In that case I would inform the department immediately.

By the way, this has nothing to do with FERPA.  FERPA doesn't protect you from intrusive questions (you might have been thinking about employment laws that protect job candidates from intrusive, irrelevant questions).  FERPA protects you from disclosure of your protected information without your consent.  For example, FERPA would protect you from this instructor obtaining your previous grade from a fellow professor, a secretary, or an administrator, and **giving that information to someone inappropriate without your consent** (for example, giving it to another student in the class).

The Department of Education has a page called "[Model Notifications of Rights under FERPA for Postsecondary Institutions](http://familypolicy.ed.gov/content/model-notifications-rights-under-ferpa-postsecondary-institutions)," which says

> A postsecondary institution may disclose PII [personally identifiable information] from the education records without obtaining prior written consent of the student to other school officials, including teachers, within the [School] whom the school has determined to have legitimate educational interests.

This means that if your instructor can convince someone on staff with access to your previous grade to give it to him (which I would guess would not be very difficult), then he doesn't need to ask you.